# How to get the id of a passed arguement in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this, the product id will be passed by an argument called productID. product_id is a hidden field in which the value will be stored. I have two fields which uses the same function. I want to specify the function from which field the value is coming from so it can update particular hidden field.

```
 function transferId(productID)
{
    document.getElementById("product_id").value =productID; 

}
```

The above function is from toke-input autocomplete where we set up the value of the selected option in a hidden field.

In the above function, product_id is the id of the hidden field.

```
<input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" /> //field where the product is selected by autocomplete
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" /> // It stores the value product_id of the product selected.
```

It works fine when I have one autocomplete text box per form, but now I have two auto complete text boxes. I need the id of the value being passed into the transferId function, so i can write an if condition to update the particular hidden field.

To be more simple, I want to take the ID of the value passed into the function.

Comment: what part of this is jQuery? you must mean JS

Comment: Can't understand your question!

Comment: *"I want to take the id of the element from where the value is getting passed to the function."* Can you clarify that? Maybe give a concrete example? Right now the question is really unclear.

Comment: i guess from what i understand, he wants to specify the id to find an hidden input with that id and place the values there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just editted the question, hope its understandable now

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
function transferId(productID)
{
    document.getElementById("product_id").value = productID.id; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

say for example i click a link:

```
<a href="#" id="link_id" onclick="transferId(this)">delete</a>
```

this link calls `transferId(this)`. the `this` in the `onclick` is the link itself. anything related to that link can be accessed via the `this`. since we passed `this`, the link itself is passed to this script, aliased as `el`:

```
function transferId(el){
    alert(el.id);            // should give you "link_id"
    alert(el.href);          // should give you "#"
}
```

from here, we get the id of the link using `el.id` as well as other attributes.

in short, just pass `this` from the event.